# Check box selection for labview

Tags: user-interface, labview

I need some help around LABVIEW.
I would like to create a control menu for a chart or Graph
that should look something like

[image]

1. the control should be dynamic based on the # of channels configured by the DAQ
2. the leftmost box is a check box that once selected will indicate to the graph that this channel should be visible
3. the name box should hold the name of the channel
4. color box will control the chart/graph color

in general like the raw legend but that is a control

I was thinking maybe the right way is to make this selection box as a standalone and that based on the selection only relevant data will pass to the graph but I'm open minded to any suggestion
appreciate the answer and explanations

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify, that you have seen the option to use the plot legend and are actively looking for another solution? (If you right-click on the plot legend you can select "Plot Visibility Checkbox" which will do what you want.

Comment: thanks,
something like that but i dont see it is being bullied base on the channels i have 
meaning that if in my GUI i pulled 3 instances of it i don't have a way to scroll it down to see all
is there a way to separate the raw legend from the chart and have a scroll menus for it?

new to LV UI :)

Comment: By dragging the raw legend around you can separate from the Chart, it will snap to corners, but you should still be able to drag it around anywhere you want. Otherwise you can resize the legend by dragging from either its side/top/bottom. The legend itself works as a 1D Array indicator, so once you've extended it you can just enable the 'Scrollbar' from the same menu to give you the vertical/horizontal scrolling you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Steve you can use the items from the waveform graph control, but if you want to do it programmatically you can use the property nodes of the control to select the plots and to change colour, name of the plots and make them visibles, in this way you can even create some personalized control to make the UI more catchy or easier to use.
You can find this properties when you right click the control and select create, in this specific case you have to go into the menu "plot" and there you can choose all the properties you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you are looking for is all available as a part of the basic LabVIEW plotting.

[image: Plot Legend menu]

Right-clicking on the plot legend presents you with the options to:

- Add an index display
- Add a scroll bar
- Add a visibility check-box for each plot

Additionally, the plot legend is treated as a 1-D array object, so you can drag on a border to resize/reshape to display as many elements as you want.